# Why is PostGIS stacking all points on top of each other? (Using ST_DWithin to find all results within 1000m radius)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

New to PostGIS/PostgreSQL...any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have two tables in a postgres db aliased as gas and ev. I'm trying to choose a specific gas station (gas.site_id=11949) and locate all EV/alternative fuel charging stations within a 1000m radius. When I run the following though, PostGIS returns a number of ev stations that are all **stacked on top of each other in the map** (see screenshot).

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? How can I get PostGIS to visualize the points within a 1000m radius of the specified gas station?

```
with myplace as (
  SELECT gas.geom 
  from nj_gas gas 
  where gas.site_id = 11949 limit 1)
select myplace.*, ev.* 
from alt_fuel ev, myplace 
where ST_DWithin(ev.geom1, myplace.geom, 1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that it visualizes the `myplace.geom` geometry instead of `ev.geom1`?

Comment: it does visualize myplace, but is there a way I can visualize both 'myplace' and the EV stations nearby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using:

````
WITH
  myplace as (
    SELECT geom as g
    FROM   nj_gas  
    WHERE  site_id = 11949 OR site_id = 11099 OR site_id = 11679 or site_id = 480522
  ), myresults AS (
SELECT ev.* 
FROM   alt_fuel AS ev
JOIN   myplace AS mp
  ON   ST_DWithin(ev.geom, mp.g, 0.1))
select * from myresults```

Thanks so much for your help @ThingumaBob and @JimJones ! Greatly appreciate it.
````

Answer (score 2):

The function [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) does not compute distances in meters using `geometry` typed parameters.

From the documentation:

> For geometry: The distance is specified in units defined by the
>   spatial reference system of the geometries. For this function to make
>   sense, the source geometries must both be of the same coordinate
>   projection, having the same SRID.

So, if you want compute distances in meters you have to use the data type `geography`:

> For geography units are in meters and measurement is defaulted to
>   use_spheroid=true, for faster check, use_spheroid=false to measure
>   along sphere.

That all being said, you have to cast the data type of your geometries. Besides that your query looks just fine - considering your data is correct :-)

```
WITH myplace as (
  SELECT gas.geom 
  FROM nj_gas gas 
  WHERE gas.site_id = 11949 LIMIT 1)
SELECT myplace.*, ev.* 
FROM alt_fuel ev, myplace 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ev.geom1::GEOGRAPHY, myplace.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 1000)
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, geom GEOGRAPHY);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,'POINT(-4.47 54.22)');

CREATE TABLE t2 (geom GEOGRAPHY);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('POINT(-4.48 54.22)'),('POINT(-4.41 54.18)');
```

Query

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT geom FROM t1 WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1)
SELECT ST_AsText(t2.geom) 
FROM j,t2 WHERE ST_DWithin(t2.geom, j.geom, 1000);

     st_astext      
--------------------
 POINT(-4.48 54.22)
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! :) Casting helped limit the # of results returned, which conceptually makes sense -- but for some reason the points shown in PostGIS remain stacked on top of each other like they were in the screenshot before casting. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you also share some data, so that we can test your query?

Comment: The datasets I used were the CSVs from: 1) https://gisdata-njdep.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/gas-service-stations-of-new-jersey?geometry=-82.583%2C31.667%2C-68.707%2C34.881 and 2) https://gisdata-njdep.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/alternative-fueled-vehicle-fueling-stations-for-new-jersey?geometry=-81.734%2C37.721%2C-67.858%2C40.699 if that helps? Sorry I'm not completely sure what you're asking for -- let me know if I can be more specific! @JimJones

Comment: @amb I just added a random example to my answer. Either you have an error with your data or your visualisation tool is playing tricks on you - PostGIS cannot be the problem:) Happy new year

Comment: Pedantic note: `ST_DWithin` computes proximity based *on the unit of the underlying CRS*; if the data is projected in a suitable *meter* based CRS, input and output are based on *meter* as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are cross joining those tables and have PostgreSQL return the cartesian product of both when selecting `myplace.*` & `ev.*`.

So while there is only one row in `myplace`, **its `geom` will be merged with every row of `alt_fuel`** (i.e. the result set will have *all* columns of *both* tables in *every possible combination* of both); since the result set thus has **two geometry columns**, your client application likely chooses **either the first, or the one called `geom`** (as opposed to `alt_fuel.geom1`) to display!

I don't see that you are interested in `myplace.geom` in the result set anyway, so I suggest to run

```
WITH
  myplace as (
    SELECT gas.geom 
    FROM   nj_gas gas 
    WHERE  gas.site_id = 11949
    LIMIT  1
  )

SELECT ev.* 
FROM   alt_fuel AS ev
JOIN   myplace AS mp
  ON   ST_DWithin(ev.geom1, mp.geom, 1000)  -- ST_DWithin(ev.geom1::GEOGRAPHY, mp.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 1000)
;
```

If, for some reason, you also want to display `myplace.geom` along with the stations, you'd have to `UNION[ ALL]` the above with a `SELECT *` on  `myplace`; note that you will also have to provide the same column list and structure (same data types!) as `alt_fuel.*` (or better, the *other side* of the `UNION[ ALL]`) in that `SELECT`!

---

Note the [suggestions made by @JimJones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59556900/6782776) about units; if your data is not projected in a *meter* based CRS (but in a *geographic reference system*; 'LonLat'), use the cast to `GEOGRAPHY` to have `ST_DWithin` consider the input as *meter* (and calculate using *spheroidal* algebra instead of planar (Euclidean))!

Comment: Consider checking out the sister board [GIS.SE] for questions regarding spatial data and the software using it!

Comment: You're right about the projection units. It is indeed possible - although I've never seen it happens :-D Thanks for the note! +1

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! The results returned in pgadmin show the correct results when I run that query, but my visualization tool isn't recognizing 'join' as a command so I'm still having trouble displaying the results. Is there another way to display the ev stations without the join statement? @ThingumaBob

Comment: @amb with the cross join notation and a filter, i.e. just run your own query from the question without selecting `myplace.*`. `JOIN`s are *fundamental* in RDB, what is wrong with that software you use??

Comment: I get an error that says "no geometry column found in query" if i remove myplace.*

Comment: @amb What's that vizualizing tool you use? Does pgAdmin return the `ec.geom1` column? Maybe alias as `geom` (`SELECT ev.geom1 AS geom ...`). This is confusing without seeing your results or having your data. The queries are correct.

Comment: Hi @ThingumaBob, the visualizing tool I'm using is Postgis editor (https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/postgis-editor). PgAdmin does return the ev.geom1 column. It is strange because the results returned in Postgis editor / visualization tool are correct (see screenshot from original post), but they fail to show up correctly on the actual map. :( I imagine the results are far enough away from each other to be distinguishable points, so I'm not sure why this is happening, especially if the queries are correct.